# Getting an error on a qsort compare function

Tags: c++builder, strcmp, qsort

I'm using C++Builder 10.4.2 and having a problem with qsort. I rarely use qsort so I might be making a clumsy mistake. Array 'buffer' is a 2D 'char' array with more than 26,000 rows of single words.

This is the call:

```
qsort((void *)buffer,wordcount,sizeof(buffer[1]),sort_function);
```

This is the compare function:

```
int TForm::sort_function(const void *a, const void *b)
{
  return( strcmp((char *)a,(char *)b) );
}
```

This is the error message. Notice that it's complaining about `sort_function` for 4th argument:

> search.h(46): candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int (__closure *)(const void *, const void *)' to 'int (*)(const void *, const void *) __attribute__((cdecl))'

What is 'int (__closure *)'? Is there a way to fix my compare function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`__closure`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Closure) is a Borland compiler extension for obtaining a pointer to a non-`static` class method, without regard to the type of class being used.  This is most commonly used in VCL/FMX components, which allow you to assign event handlers from any class you want, which is not something that standard C++ typically allows you to do.

`qsort()` expects a C-style function pointer in the 4th parameter.  You can't get such a pointer to a *non-`static`* class method.

To solve this, you need to use either:

- a standalone function
- a `static` class method
- a *non-capturing* C++ lambda (C++11 or higher only)

Since your `sort_function()` does not need access to your `TForm` object, declaring `sort_function()` as `static` would be the simplest fix:

```cpp
// .h

class TForm
{
...
private:
    static int sort_function(const void *a, const void *b);
    void doSomething();
...
};
```

```cpp
// .cpp

int TForm::sort_function(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return strcmp((const char *)a, (const char *)b);
}

void TForm::doSomething()
{
    ...
    qsort(buffer, wordcount, sizeof(buffer[1]), sort_function);
    ...
}
```

However, it really should be a standalone function instead since it really has no relation to your `TForm` class at all:

```cpp
// .cpp

static int sort_function(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return strcmp((const char *)a, (const char *)b);
}

void TForm::doSomething()
{
    ...
    qsort(buffer, wordcount, sizeof(buffer[1]), sort_function);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Excellent, Remy, as always. Thank you.